# Store matched characters in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am new and that I want to know is how I can store a matched characters in a Flex program and then print them in one line in main. I have the patterns and rules below:

```
ID  [A]
ID1 [B]
ID2 [C]
ID3 [D]

%%
{ID}  
{ID1}  
{ID2}  
{ID3}
```

Comment: Isn't that what `yytext` is for?  Of course, as it stands, you've only got default actions for the patterns (and to my way of thinking, `ID` should have a numeric suffix — but that's an æsthetics issue), so you'll need to do some work to give `main()` a chance to process the matched characters.
Having single-letter character classes as shown is a bit odd, though not formally wrong.  You should use some space, too.

Comment: yeah there is a yytext() in main

Comment: `yytext()`?  A function?  I'm used to thinking that `yytext` is either `char yytext[];` or `char *yytext;`, and I seem to remember which variant was available depends on which variant of Lex is used, and I don't recall what Flex does.  You need to add something after each pattern to return to `main()` — something like `{ return 1; }` to indicate successful matching.  Anything not matched is ignored, IIRC.

Comment: the user when he gives ABCE the check is done for every single character and when the match is finished i want to print ABCE is matched in main section

Comment: You misunderstand the functionality of Flex.  You've said "one token is A; one token is B; one token is C; one token is D; one token is E".  If you want your program to aggregate all these, you'll have to arrange to do that — the tokenizing code in the Flex lexical analyzer identifies tokens and arranges to execute your chosen code when the token is recognized (and `yytext` points to (contains) the most recently matched token — but only the most recently matched token; not any prior or subsequent tokens).

Comment: I did this token that it check that letters from A to E there is only once

Comment: So how can i check and in the same time save the id that is matched???

Comment: That's verging on a grammar — territory for Yacc/Bison rather than Lex/Flex.  Does the sequence of the letters matter, or is it 'just one of each'?  Does it have to be all 5 letters, or can 4 be OK?  Does it matter which 4?  What should happen if there's an `F`' or an `a` in the data?  A newline?  This is rapidly getting to be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — what are you really trying to do and what are the rules which constrain you (teacher-imposed rules about what you can and cannot use).

Comment: i want to check with the flex analyzer when the user gives strings if the strings contains characters from A to E and in the string every character exist only one time.Before i used only one Id token and i saw that i have problem with the second part of what i want to do

Comment: the pattern is only for capital letters from A to E .For example, ADC,EACD etc.

Comment: OK; what should your code do when a user types something else?  Cry?  Reject? Silently accept? Chastise the user?  Crash?  You should decide; the default action is to echo the unrecognized character.

Comment: when the user gives AABC the programm print A letter exist more than once.The only now that i want to do is to save in a variable or in a array the matched letters and then i want to print them in one line in the main.And i dont know how to do it .I tried in definition char mag and then after each pattern i put mag=mag+yytext and (the error was assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) for the recognition and capture part of the work — it also enforces uniqueness.  It uses `assert()` to ensure that tokens are single (non-null) characters.

```
%{
#include <assert.h>
%}
%option noinput
%option nounput
%option noyywrap
ID0 [A]
ID1 [B]
ID2 [C]
ID3 [D]
ID4 [E]
%%
{ID0}       { printf("{ID0}: %s\n", yytext); return 1; }
{ID1}       { printf("{ID1}: %s\n", yytext); return 1; }
{ID2}       { printf("{ID2}: %s\n", yytext); return 1; }
{ID3}       { printf("{ID3}: %s\n", yytext); return 1; }
{ID4}       { printf("{ID4}: %s\n", yytext); return 1; }
.           { printf("  .  : %s\n", yytext);           }
%%

int main(void)
{
    char token[512] = "";
    char *ptr = token;

    /* Efficiency and safety is not under discussion */
    while (yylex())
    {
        assert(yytext[0] != '\0' && yytext[1] == '\0');
        if (strchr(token, yytext[0]) == 0)
            *ptr++ = yytext[0];
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    printf("Token sequence: [%s]\n", token);
    return 0;
}
```

(I renamed `ID` to `ID0` for better consistency of the names.)

Example run (I used the name `fx83.l` for the source and hence `fx83` as the name of the program generated from the source):

```
$ ./fx83 <<< "aBcDeAbCdEFf"
  .  : a
{ID1}: B
  .  : c
{ID3}: D
  .  : e
{ID0}: A
  .  : b
{ID2}: C
  .  : d
{ID4}: E
  .  : F
{ID0}: A
{ID1}: B
  .  : d
{ID2}: C
{ID3}: D
  .  : e
{ID4}: E
{ID4}: E
  .  : f

Token sequence: [BDACE]
$
```

(I don't think it matters, but I'm using `flex 2.5.35 Apple(flex-31)` on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 with GCC 6.2.0.)

Comment: thank you so much for your help and your time.Now is ok